# Selecting unique rows from a table that are not found in two other tables in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have three tables (forward, reverse and probe) that all contain the same columns (Query, QueryLength, Hit, Start, End, Strand, Description, Length, Percent_id, Score, Evalue). 
I want to get the unique rows from 'forward' where the 'Hit' is not found in either the 'reverse' table or the 'probe' table. With 'AND' I don't get any results, with 'OR' I get the comparison only with reverse.

`CREATE TABLE f AS SELECT * FROM forward WHERE forward.Hit NOT IN (SELECT Hit from reverse) OR (SELECT Hit FROM probe)`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `... OR (SELECT Hit FROM probe)`, you have a scalar subquery, i.e., the database looks only at the first value returned by the subquery, and treats it as 'true' if the value is non-zero.

To check whether a value is found in another table, you have to use IN (in both cases):

```
SELECT * FROM forward
WHERE Hit NOT IN (SELECT Hit FROM reverse)
  AND Hit NOT IN (SELECT Hit FROM probe)
```

If you want to check entire records instead of only one column, you can use EXCEPT:

```
SELECT * FROM forward
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM reverse
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM probe
```